How to add plugin with version in build.gradle.kts?
I'm trying to add a new plugin to my project
In the user manual of the plugin, it recommend me add as following into the module's build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.company.myplugin' version '0.0.1'
}

However, my new project created gradle file is in Kotlin i.e. build.gradle.kts.
The plugins are in kotlin format as following
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

I tried
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.company.myplugin", "0.0.1")
}

or
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id 'com.company.myplugin' version '0.0.1'
}

Both also not working. How can I add the new plugin into my project along with the version?

version is an infix extension function, so:
id("com.company.myplugin") version "0.0.1"

This function is basically syntactic sugar over the method version:
id("com.company.myplugin").version("0.0.1")

Here's an excerpt from the source code, just in case you don't believe me:
/**
 * Specify the version of the plugin to depend on.
 *
 * Infix version of [PluginDependencySpec.version].
 */
infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String?): PluginDependencySpec = version(version)

Detailed explanation
plugins is a higher-order function, which takes a function as argument (the following braced block { ... }). This function has the type of PluginDependenciesSpecScope.() -> Unit (i.e. implicitly accepts a this argument of type PluginDependenciesSpecScope).
id() is a method of the PluginDependenciesSpecScope class. This method returns an instance of a class implementing the Java interface PluginDependencySpec, which has a version method.
This method is itself called by an infix extension function of the same name, which, probably, was defined just for the sake of it.
All of these are standard Kotlin syntax.
